# Quartz clustered scheduler threadCount

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We have defined quartz clustered scheduler having 4 node with following property for threadCount

```
 threadPool.threadCount = 25
```

Can someone please confirm that is it 25 thread on each node i.e. 25 * 4 = 100 or it is total of 25 for all 4 node?

Answer (score 1):

You have a threadcount of 25 on each node, i.e. 100 threads in total.